# How to rename app icon?

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios4

In Xcode4, I have changed the product name in Target | Build Settings | Product Name.  But the app icon still has the old name.  I have done a clean and deleted the app from the simulator.  Any suggestions what I'm missing?

EDIT:
After changing the Bundle Display Name in info.plist, the icon name has changed.  Which one of these is the correct place?  Looks like info.plist?  What good is the product name in Build Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Bundle display name" in your info.plist, if this is what you mean by "app icon".

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Info.plist (likely names AppName-Info.plist) and see how the Bundle Name is set. Sounds like it is not set to $(PRODUCT_NAME).